# Adding many rows at once in hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate

, Iam working on this project in hibernate, where the user enters the quantity based on this number i need to display the unique fields in the next form (For example if the user enters quantity as 5 then 5 MAC Address and DeviceSerial fields are shown in  the jsp page, the other common information about the devices are entered in the same form where quantity is entered) and all this information should be put into the database . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this page: [webpage](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

You should open a transaction, save all entities (in loop), at the end commit the transaction and close the session. You should not commit for every single record but at the end.

Referenced to [Goran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100282/goran-nastov) 
or

if you can use hibernateTemplate instead of session then you can save your object list by using saveOrUpdateAll(Collection entities).

Although HibernateTemplate saveOrUpdateAll does save a collection at once but, it will use the same loop logic of saving the object and flushing

Comment: Yeah i did go through the link,according to what i understood batch update is for updating entire records with the same value but here i want it done individually mac address and device sl  no are unique to a record ( i would have already inserted the records with these fields blank) it would also help if u tell me how to get the controller part for this ! Thank you :)

Comment: @Ynk1993 , by controller u mean to refer MVC controller

Answer (score 1):

You should go for **Batch Insert** in hibernate.

Batch Insertion is a powerful feature of hibernate particularly useful when you are importing data from other systems in batch. If you do not use batch feature of hibernate, your application's performance may decrease dramatically at the time of insertion of many records.

For more information visit [hibernate tutorials](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts).